# Add specific printer output tray as new printer

Tags: server, virtual-printer

I need to add printer **output tray** which has virtual name how can I add that tray as printer in Ubuntu.

I need to add that printer with shell command not in GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

1. I need to add new printer as shell script which can be part of my charm config.
2. With `lpadmin` (adding new network /shared printer) there is an option `part -o [options]`
3. All options are printer specific and all defined in printer's PPD
4. Install printer with correct PPD
5. Look at all "options" with `lpoptions -p [Printer Name -l]`; it displays all printer's features as options and finds Output Tray or Output Bin
6. In my case it was "OutputBin=" however in one of my printers the tray or bin numbers were Bin1,Bin2, ... and the other one was MailBoxBin1, MailBoxBin2,..

So the correct command is:

```
lpadmin  -p [printer local name] -v smb://domain/user:pass@printer_server_IP/Printer_shared_name  [ or socket://printer_IP:port/ ] virologic/apprunner:Y0g1Bear@10.196.1.250/ITPrinterBW -E -P [printer PPD file]-o OutputBin=Bin1
```